# Node-Webkit Facebook integration

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, coffeescript, node-webkit

I am building a newsreader-ish desktop app using node-webkit

https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit

which is basically server and client at the same time. My Problem with the facebook API is the following: i want the user of my app to login and present them their current wall-postings and the stuff like this. In addition, i have a couple of news-items from other sources, which should be like-able/share-able from this user.

The whole app is a single-page JS (more exactly: coffeescript) thing with multiple components, a hard redirect is impossible.

Every login-possibility shown in the API seems not suited for my type of application. What is the best way to connect to facebook, without having a hard redirect and without an own URI to redirect to?

Comment: The [client-side SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) can login and get an auth token without a page refresh.

Comment: using the unmodified code from the tutorial-page: Failed to load resource file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js ... crossdomain problem? i just removed the channel-attribute (don't have a URI), and set my correct AppID.

Comment: You'll have to use an absolute URL rather than the protocol-relative one from the docs.  Modify `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/`... to `https://connect.facebook.net/`...

Comment: Okay, done. Now the Crossdomain-stuff: "One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

Comment: seems that my problem with the client sdk is the following: i simply can't register a url in the facebook-app-settings, and obviously facebook checks if the requesting client matches this url. Isn't there something like "ANY" which i can write there intead of an url?

Comment: No, there is not. Login has to be tied to an existing domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're developing a standalone client application, not a website, I wouldn't try to use their Javascript API, because it assumes it's being run on some website.

You might have more luck with the [unofficial Node.js APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/third-party-sdks/#nodejs), seeing as node-webkit allows you to make calls to any Node.js library from within the DOM.

If you still have no success, try letting the user log into Facebook itself, presenting its login page in an `<iframe>`. Then you might be able to make HTTP calls, either through AJAX or through Node.js HTTP APIs, to call Facebook's internal APIs directly.

Comment: my primary question was about getting the plain access token. however, i found a solution for this, using a child-window. +1 for leading me away from their client-sdk, and another +1 for pointing me to the node.js lib's for further usage. you'll get the bounty if noone offers another genius solution :)

Comment: @Hisako I am facing the same problem. I want to integrate a facebook connect inside a node webkit application. I just want to retrieve access tokens. How did you manage to do it? I am having the same error "One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains". You talk about child window. What do you mean? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I opened the OAuth URL inside a new child window from within my App, and "watched" the url. Once User logged in, the url changes to something that has the access token appended after the '#' symbol.

Comment: @Hisako I'm trying to do the same thing but I can't "watch" the url. After the child window has been redirected to the facebook authorize page,  all my eventListener attached to the child window stop working. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do not use an eventlistener. Just fire a setInterval and check the url every 50 or so miliseconds. dirty, but worked for me. :)

Comment: @Hisako, I tried it and I confirm that it's work fine. Now I can get the token. Thank you :).