# How to get access token from node-webkit for a desktop app without hosting page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, node-webkit

I'm trying to create a desktop app with node-webkit. A part of this app require the use of facebook to get/post some content to any profile (facebook user) that use my desktop app on my personal computer.

Regarding facebook api documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0) , I have to manually implement the login flow and use the following URI as the redirect URI:  `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

Currently, in my node-webkit app, via a child window (a popup), a user can login to facebook  and authorize my desktop app to interact with it's profile. 
Here is a part of the code:

```
var url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myclientID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=publish_actions";
loginWindow = window.open(url, 'Login facebook', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=480,width=640', false);
```

After that, the user is redirected to the following URI and as mentioned in the doc, the access token appear correctly:

`https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=theBigTokenString&expires_in=3864`.

But it appears only for few seconds and after that the url is replaced by `https://www.facebook.com/connect/blank.html#_=_` (with a security warning message).

I've read some post that propose to add eventListener like `hashchange` to the opened window in order to capture the access token. But after some redirect within the child window, I'm no longer available to interact with it via javascript.

So finally, I can't get the access token that the child window has retrieved and make visible for few seconds.

Is anyone can help me to get this user access token with node-webkit?
I really don't want to use a server (for hosting a web page) between my desktop app and facebook.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Set your own redirect url instead. That way you are redirected there

Comment: @WizKid how can I do that without a web server? Currently my desktop app doesn't run any local http server (I really want to avoid hosting something in a cloud). Do you mean that I need a web server? Is it possible to put a redirect URL that is not associated to any existing domain (for example is localhost accepted ? )

Comment: Oh, if it is a desktop app just detect the access_token in the url and use that

Comment: I'm blocked with this part. Because of the full javascript nature of my app (node-webkit), I've got difficulties to intercept this token that appear briefly in URL of the child window (that was popup for the login process). Do you known any workarounds to catch this token from a child popup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the help of an other question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419985/node-webkit-facebook-integration)) I found a solution to my problem.

I post the code that I use now and I Hope it will help someone else:

```
var url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?&client_id=myBigClientID&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=publish_actions";

function Response() {
  this.access_token = null; 
  this.expires_in  = null;
};

var response = new Response();

//function called every 500ms to check if token is in url
window.hashUpdate = function() {
  if(window.loginWindow.closed){
    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    start(); //just a callback that I'm using to start another part of my application (after I caught the token)
  }
  else {
    var url = window.loginWindow.document.URL;
    var tabUrl = url.split("#"); //first split to separate the domain part and the parameter part
    var paramString = tabUrl[1]; //I concerned only by the second part after the '#'
    if(paramString != undefined){
      var allParam = paramString.split("&");
      for (var i = 0; i < allParam.length; i++) {
        var oneParamKeyValue = allParam[i].split("=");
        response[oneParamKeyValue[0]] = oneParamKeyValue[1]; //store my token in form of key => value
      };

      //close the window after 1500ms
      setTimeout(function(){
        window.loginWindow.close();
      }, 1500);
    }

  }
}

//open the url and start the watching process
window.loginWindow = window.open(this.url, 'Login facebook', false);
this.intervalId = window.setInterval("window.hashUpdate()", 500);
```

Comment: @naike This looks great, thank you. One question though, what did you specify as your app domain/site URL in the Facebook Developer Console? I'm getting URL/domain errors using this approach from a node-webkit app.

Comment: @Jakemmarsh For the app domain/site, It was localhost. I can't checked because I've recently delete my facebook account but I'm sure I used localhost to do/test my app. Share you're code here if you want help :).

Comment: If you want to do without polling for changes to document.URL, you should be able to listen to the 'loaded' event, which will fire when the URL changes in the popup during the fb login flow, and then you should be able to extract which of the URLs is the one with the access_token. Eg: loginWindow.on('loaded', function() { console.log(this.window.location.href); })

Comment: I simplified and made it a bit more re-usable: https://gist.github.com/konsumer/2298cc4f8b7b0a1ee9fa

Comment: @konsumer What is the redirect url to be used for a desktop application?

Comment: doesn't matter, just a URL that you set for your app.